# JGit/NGit Wrapper for Push/Pull results

Tags: c#, git, formatting, jgit

Can somebody point me to (or share) a simple wrapper for JGit/NGit Push/Pull output results?
How do I mimic the output from CGit?
Which information should be included in the GUI?

Here is what I have come up with so far (I am using Mono/NGit):

```
using System;
using NGit;
using NGit.Api;
using NGit.Storage.File;
using NGit.Transport;
using Sharpen;

namespace RepoSync.Service
{
    class NGitPushResultAdapter : ICommandResponse
    {
        public NGitPushResultAdapter (Iterable<PushResult> pushResults)
        {
            foreach (var pushResult in pushResults) {
                var remoteUpdates = pushResult.GetRemoteUpdates ();
                foreach (var remoteUpdate in remoteUpdates) {
                                    // TODO: Which infos to include?
                    Msg += remoteUpdate.GetStatus ();
                }
            }
        }

        public string Msg { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public GitCommandException Exception { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean like the [jGit procelain API](http://jgit.info/javadoc/org/eclipse/jgit/api/package-summary.html)? do you want specifically C#?

Comment: A jgit example is also acceptable, because ngit is jgit converted to C#.

Comment: OK, so the jGit porcelain API provides some wrappers. For instance, the [PullResult](http://jgit.info/javadoc/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PullResult.html) and [PushResult](http://jgit.info/javadoc/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/PushResult.html). But I don't know if it's what you're looking for, the status not being enough according to your code?

Comment: @Vince There is no difference between C# and Java. Jgit/NGit PushResult/PullResult is at my hand. I am lazy... I would like to have the same string as Message in my Gui as the command line output (from CGit). Since JGit/NGit is a reimplemtation, I was wondering how to catch that. This is just a question if somebody has formatted JGit/NGit Push/Pull output for a GUI...